# How to use UIMotionEffect in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uimotioneffect

Any idea how to use UIMotionEffect in SwiftUI? I was thinking there might be a way to connect the motion effect to a state variable and then using that variable in SwiftUI we get a similar result to UIKit.

Simple UIKit example

```
let value = 12

let verticalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.y", type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = value
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = -value

let horizontalMotionEffect = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "layer.transform.translation.x", type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = value
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = -value

let group = UIMotionEffectGroup()
group.motionEffects = [horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect]
view.addMotionEffect(group)
```

Comment: Use **combine**

Comment: Can you explain how? Also please use answer, so I can tick your response.

Comment: It's little too much for answer. Please provide minimal UIKit version code, so I can change it to SwiftUI version.

Comment: Ok I have added a UIKit example